# Firebase and json-server

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting, json-server

I'm currently using [json-server repo](https://github.com/typicode/json-server#routes) to emulate my back-end db and server for a prototype. To use/start json-server, I need to execute `npm run json:server`.

I've deployed my project to firebase but can't find a way to access a cmd or run that command from my own git-bash.

Is there any way of doing so or firebase doesn't allow to run commands on their end?

Comment: Firebase is 18+ products. Which one are you trying to use?

Comment: I'm trying to use their hosting service

Comment: That helps     Did you read https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/use-cases#what_can_you_host?

Comment: Thank you so much! Figured out I need to use Firebase Function!!

Comment: Yes sorry, I in fact do not have enough reputation to upvote it. I did add it as the answer though. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to run small Node.js snippets on Firebase, have a look at the integration between Firebase Hosting and Cloud Functions.

Also see the Firebase documentation on [what can you host on Firebase?](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/use-cases#what_can_you_host) and the overview documentation for [running micro-services on Firebase Hosting and Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/serverless-overview).